# Just get date stamp once in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

To datestamp a cell in Excel I use the forumula : =NOW()

The problem is that as I datestamp new cells all other cells which contain the formula NOW() are updated with the new datestamp. Is there a formula I can use which will just datestamp the  cell once, and not recompute the date each time ?

Comment: No. Not unless you use VBA

Comment: Copy and paste values is your only option. Formulas will always re-compute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source [**Insert a static date or time**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-HP003056107.aspx#BMinsert_a_static_date_or_time):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> for Date
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> for Time
- both in sequence for Date+Time